# How to use react-bubble-chart-d3 in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Im using '@weknow/react-bubble-chart-d3' in my project, but I cannot import it in typescript

I already made 'desc.d.ts' in root directory

```js
declare module '@weknow/react-bubble-chart-d3'
```

and added in tsconfig.json

```js
  "include": ["src", "desc.d.ts"]
```

but it works like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwS2G.png)

Is there a way to import BubbleChart library in typescript?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will mostly not work, as the package is written for javascript not typescript.

Comment: That's not true, any JavaScript code is compatible with TypeScript but not the other way around.

Comment: The provided package does not contain `.d.ts` files, which means that the types of variables and other parameters are not defined when creating the package. Therefore, when we attempt to use it in TypeScript, it raises complaints about type errors, and if we stop strict types in tsconfig.json then it will work.